# Undefined index error while trying to run $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']

Tags: php

I was trying to print the superglobal variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` for testing a proxy blocker for my website. When i open the file, the server returns this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/test.php on line 2

This is what is inside the file:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
?>
```

What's the problem? is that variable not printable? It seems the error that appeard when you do not define a variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452938/how-to-use-http-x-forwarded-for-properly

Comment: From [PHP doc](https://secure.php.net/reserved.variables.server): `You may or may not find any of the following elements in $_SERVER. Note that few, if any, of these will be available (or indeed have any meaning) if running PHP on the command line.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `$_SERVER` variables prefixed with `HTTP_` represent HTTP headers that you've received from the client.

The only HTTP header that is always present is `Host`, so ... for everything else, you have to check if it exists first.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if(array_key_exists("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR", $_SERVER))
```

To check whether the variable exists before trying to access it

Answer (score 0):

This error will ocurr when the proxy forward isn't done correctly. Could you share more information?

Also I would recommend to use **getenv** method and check before if var exists (both, the condition and the allocation can be written inside the if statement):

```
if ($forwarded = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) {
    echo $forwarded;
}
```

fyi: getenv returns `FALSE` if the environment var doesn't exist.