# Can I change the value of REMOTE_ADDR (and others) using htaccess or PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, server-variables

I'm using a CDN and a firewall that sends the visitors' IP through a specific `$_SERVER` var. The goal is to avoid changing all the files through the CMS I'm using.

My problem is that since I'm using the firewall, people are not redirected as they should and records of IP are false because `REMOTE_ADDR` is changed by the firewall.

If it is not possible or I shouldn't do it, can someone explain why?

**EDIT:** you can using PHP. For example

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] = $_SERVER['VAR_NAME'];
```

Comment: Try it and see if it works.

Comment: Should your take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38739305/7415107

Comment: Seems stupid, but thank you. I tried before but it didn't work (I think my code was wrong). Because of your message I tried again and it's working great. Thank you @Script47 . Is it deprecated to do this ?

Comment: @AndréDS Thank you, but I knew which var is used to send me the IP (a specific one, from the firewall).