# Not getting correct IP address on the web site

Tags: php, ip

I am using https://ident.me/ for getting IP of anybody who visits my web site. (https://notablee.co/get_ip)

But I am only getting the Shared Hosting IP (50.87.141.159) instead of the Visitors IP Address.

```
$ip = file_get_contents('https://ident.me/');
```

Comment: It would help immensely if we could see the code that you are using to do this...

Comment: You might have better luck simply using `$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` - the `ident.me` is located on your server so is reporting it's ip address

Answer (score 0):

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Fixed this. Thanks to 'Professor Abronsius' for a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

While your answer is not entirely wrong, you should consider that your code sits behind a loadbalancer or proxy. In this case, the $_SERVER array should contain the field X_HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR which contains a list of all previous IP addresses as a comma-separated string.

Also read this SO article
[How to use HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452938/how-to-use-http-x-forwarded-for-properly)