# Capturing something unique through php of local machine accessing the site

Tags: php, function, unique, identifier

Ip address is considered to be unique identifier of local machine. But When proxy servers are used, then every machine using the proxy server uses the same ip address. Hence the $_SERVER[] variable just gives the same ip address for all the machines. I really needed a php function to capture the ipv4 address of the machine, if not anything unique will do. So that i can identify or differentiate between users accessing the site from different machine. Please help me.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527345/determine-if-user-is-using-proxy

Comment: It's not possible to get the local ip-adress of a computer, otherwise routers would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use sessions or cookies? These can be used to differentiate between users.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the php function `get_browser` ?

This is not able to differentiate user with 100% success but could be a real clue as it return a 26 item array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Answer (score 0):

What about setting a `$_COOKIE` http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

```
setcookie("was_here", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], strtotime('+1 year'));  /* expire after 1 year */
```

Comment: What a quick reply!!!! Suppose i set the cookie for a machine.. Then what? when the user again comes from that machine, will I be able to find him/her out?? If yes, how?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp might be more what you are lookng for.