# return null when request is coming from proxy , tor users

Tags: php, proxy, detection

I have created an ad network, everything is completed but I want to detect fraud clicks so I think it's a good idea to block OR return null request to proxy and Tor users for preventing fraud clicks. I don't want to show my ads on proxy and Tor users.

I have already tried [Determine If User Is Using Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527345/determine-if-user-is-using-proxy) code but it's not working quite well. If I am blocking `X_FORWARDED_FOR` then it will block Opera Mini and Some Other browsers also.

Comment: I don't mean to be unnecessarily rude, but the fact you're asking this question when you believe your ad network is "complete" suggests you are in *way* over your head. For example, you make no mention of running behavioural analysis on the clicks you receive. Blocking Tor/proxy users in order to prevent fraudulent clicks is like using a Band-Aid to patch up the Titanic.

Comment: sorry if I made you angry but if I will not block Proxy & Tor Users then they will come from New IP & UserAgent every Minuts, Every Day, that's why I think its good,


if you have any other solutions for Fraud Clicks Detection then Please Share It.. :)

Comment: I'm not angry, I just don't believe that you fully understand the scope of the problem you're going to have to deal with it. Tor/proxy usage is just the tip of the iceberg. How do you cope with hijacked browsers? How do you cope with XSS attacks? How do you cope with [Mechanical Turk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Mechanical_Turk) fraud? All of these issues (and more!) will need to be addressed by any click fraud protection you intend to use, or you will find your ad network going out of business very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect Tor users using TorDNSEL - https://www.torproject.org/projects/tordnsel.html.en.
Implementation example - https://github.com/assafmo/IsTorExit.